# Dealing with numerous dependencies and $http expectations in an Angular test

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular controller:

```
     angular.module('dashboard')
        .controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$interval', 'domainService', 'messageService', 'currentUserAccount', 'unreadMessagesCount', 'latestMessages', function ($rootScope, $scope, $interval, domainService, messageService, currentUserAccount, unreadMessagesCount, latestMessages) {

        $scope.$on('useraccount:updated', function () {
           domainService.currentUserAccount().success(function (data) {
            $scope.currentUserAccount = data;
        });
    });
   ...
```

It has a number of dependencies.

I am just trying to test that this controller does set the `currentUserAccount` on the `$scope`.

I have the following Angular test - that works fine:

```
describe('DashboardCtrl', function () {
    var scope, httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('bignibou', 'dashboard'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, domainService, messageService, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            domainService: domainService,
            messageService: messageService,
            currentUserAccount: {data: {firstName: 'John'}},
            unreadMessagesCount: 0,
            latestMessages: []
        });

        httpBackend = $httpBackend;

        //TODO: do I need all those expectations?
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/signup-roles').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/parents-needs').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/childcare-worker-types').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/childcare-types').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/all-day-to-time-slots').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/regular-day-to-time-slots').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/info').respond({build: {version: '1.0'}});
        httpBackend.whenGET(/app.+/).respond({});

        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/current-useraccount').respond({id: 42, firstName: 'Pedro'});
    }));
    it('should handle user account updated', function () {
        scope.$emit('useraccount:updated');
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.currentUserAccount.firstName).toEqual('Pedro');
    });
});
```

However, I am not satisfied with it as it has numerous dependencies - and worse the outstanding expectations/requests are getting unwieldy.

The reason for this is that I rely on the top-level module - imported above as `bignibou`...

Here is this module's declaration:

```
angular.module('bignibou', [
    'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router', 'ui.utils', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'angularMoment', 'checklist-model', 'ngTagsInput', 'angular-loading-bar', 'cfp.loadingBar',
    'home', 'signup', 'signin', 'signout', 'navbar', 'dashboard', 'useraccount', 'advertisement', 'search', 'geolocation', 'utils', 'message'
]);
angular.module('home', []);
angular.module('signup', []);
angular.module('signin', []);
angular.module('signout', []);
angular.module('navbar', []);
angular.module('dashboard', []);
angular.module('useraccount', []);
angular.module('advertisement', []);
angular.module('search', []);
angular.module('geolocation', []);
angular.module('message', []);
angular.module('utils', []);
```

Then within the `utils` module, I have a number of `$http` calls:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'domainService', function ($rootScope, domainService) {
    domainService.signupRoles().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.signupRoles = param.data;
    });
    domainService.parentsNeeds().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.parentsNeeds = param.data;
    });
    domainService.childcareWorkerTypes().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.childcareWorkerTypes = param.data;
    });
    domainService.childcareTypes().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.childcareTypes = param.data;
    });
    domainService.allDayToTimeSlots().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.allDayToTimeSlots = param.data;
    });
    domainService.regularDayToTimeSlots().then(function (param) {
        $rootScope.regularDayToTimeSlots = param.data;
    });
}])
```

Now how can I redesign/refactor my test so that I can avoid all the `$http` calls expectations?

To put it another way, I am testing `DashboardCtrl` that relies on the `domainService` dependency in the `utils` module which itself does a number of `$http` calls.

This forces me to have to setup numerous expectations in my test leading to clumsy test code...

Can someone please advise a solution to this issue? What I am missing? Is this a test design issue or a application design issue?

Comment: Put this run() block in a module that you don't load in the tests.

Comment: I thought it be easiest to always include the top-level module in my tests (the module that pulls all dependencies) in my case 'bignibou' but it does not seem to be a good idea. I guess this issue forces me to reason better about my app's dependency graph. Do you recommend any tool that could help me visualize my dependency graph?

Comment: Here is a  nice tool to help visualize one app's dependency graph: https://github.com/filso/ng-dependency-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User JB Nizet put me on the right track by suggesting I rearrange my dependencies.

Using this nice tool http://angularjs-graph.org/ or [github](https://github.com/filso/ng-dependency-graph/), I was able to visualize my angular dependency graph and rearrange the dependencies thereby avoiding having to load all dependencies in my test.

My test is now more concise and I avoid the unnecessary expectations:

```
describe('DashboardCtrl', function () {
    var $scope, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('dashboard', 'utils', 'message'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, domainService, messageService, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope,
            domainService: domainService,
            messageService: messageService,
            currentUserAccount: {data: {firstName: 'John'}},
            unreadMessagesCount: 0,
            latestMessages: []
        });

        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/current-useraccount').respond({id: 42, firstName: 'Pedro'});
    }));
    it('should handle user account updated', function () {
        $scope.$emit('useraccount:updated');
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($scope.currentUserAccount.firstName).toEqual('Pedro');
    });
});
```

One can see I no longer pull the top-level `bignibou` (the name of my app) module and I then selectively use the required modules.